# I have a linear layout with four image buttons , I want them to be evenly placed inside the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_layout_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_layout_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_top"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/message_button"
            style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/message_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/messageicon"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video_call_button"
            style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/videocall_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/videoicon"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/audio_call_button"
            style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/audiocall_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/audiocall" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/drop_in_button"
            style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dropin_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/dropinicon"
            android:visibility="gone" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

If I hide 3 items I don't get the remaining one at the exact center, I hide them randomly, I need the remaining items to be evenly spread with equal spaces.

Comment: Use android:layout_weight="1" to each ImageButton

Comment: How do you hide the items, `GONE` or `INVISIBLE` ? and post the `contactCardButtonStyle`

Comment: Please share an screenshot of the current layout and your expected layout.

Comment: `... evenly spaced` sounds like: "**use weights**".

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an weightSum to your parent layout and then set the layout_weight for each of your ImageButton as follows

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_layout_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_layout_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_top"
    android:orientation="horizantal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/message_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/message_button"
        android:src="@mipmap/messageicon"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/video_call_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/videocall_button"
        android:src="@mipmap/videoicon"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight ="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/audio_call_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/audiocall_button"
        android:src="@mipmap/audiocall" 
        android:layout_weight ="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/drop_in_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        style="@style/contactCardButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/imagebutton_margin_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dropin_button"
        android:src="@mipmap/dropinicon"
        android:visibility="gone" 
        android:layout_weight ="1" />
```

Please set an orientation to the LinearLayout here i have set it to horizontal hence the width is 0dp for all the ImageButton(s). Similarly if you are setting it as vertical you need to set the height as 0dp.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i missed that have edited the answer.